# Cancelling Web service call in android if Internet is not making communication

Tags: android, android-asynctask, httprequest

Hi I am developing an app which includes multiple web service calls.

I check the network connectivity using connectivity manager, but some time it shows connected although there is no data communication.

I have seen some application will attempt for certain time and then show please try again later.

So instead my application is getting force closed, can anyone please help me out on this one.

Comment: Can you show us your function that connects to the webserver? And the stacktrace?

Comment: Refer this link : http://www.androidhive.info/2012/07/android-detect-internet-connection-status/

Comment: Thanks for Commenting but what i am talking about is when 3g is connected but still not able to get the response due to slow speed and got stuck in an endless state where it is trying to connect to server.......